# how to fix Error " Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , all.vars(Terms), drop = FALSE) : undefined columns selected" in caret package

Tags: r, r-caret

i encounter this error :

> Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , all.vars(Terms), drop = FALSE) :
> undefined columns selected

when i use `caret` to do regression with using bootstrap for 3 different cluster(index column)

```
library("tidyverse")
library("lattice")

library("caret")
library("janitor")
data<- read.csv("C:/Users/asus/Desktop/test.csv",header = TRUE)
mydata <- data.frame(index = data$cluster,
                     x     = data[,3:4],
                     y     = data[,5])
tab <- table(mydata$index)
tab
sample_n(mydata, 3)
attach(mydata)
mylist <- list()
mydata <- clean_names(mydata)
head(mydata)
for (i in 1:length(unique(mydata$index))) {
  # define training control
  train.ctrl <- trainControl(method = "boot", number = tab[i])
  # train the model
  mylist[[i]] <- train(mydata[index == i,"y"] ~ mydata[index ==i,"x_xa"] + mydata[index == i,"x_xb"], data = data.frame(mydata), method = "lm",
                       trControl = train.ctrl)
  print(mylist[[i]])
  summary(mylist[[i]])
}
```

here you can see my data:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subset the data within each iteration and apply the same formula, since each dataset would have the same columns. Try to go through the [help page](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/formula) again. Also, please include only the relevant code.

Let's say your data is like this:

```
set.seed(111)
mydata = data.frame(index = sample(1:3,500,replace=TRUE),
                    x1 = rnorm(500),
                    x2 = rnorm(500),
                     y = runif(500)
                    )
```

Then something like this:

```
library(caret)

tab <- table(mydata$index)
mylist <- list()

for (i in unique(mydata$index)) {

  train.ctrl <- trainControl(method = "boot", number = tab[i])
  mylist[[i]] <- train(y ~ x1 + x2, 
                       data = subset(mydata, index == i),
                       method = "lm",
                       trControl = train.ctrl)
}
```